# How can I add a button which could hidden or expand my side-bar of post page?

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll

[Here is one of my post](http://hypergroups.github.io/2013/09/11/Alfors-Complex-Analysis-2.1.1/)

How can I add a button(《, I've saw someone's page could do such effect.) that can hidden my sidebar and re-click to expand?

Is it an easy thing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's pretty easy if you're using jQuery, and a bit harder if you're not.

HTML:

```
<button id="toggle">←</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $('.span4').slideToggle();

        if ($('.toggle').text() == "←") {
            $('.toggle').text("→");
        } else {
            $('.toggle').text("←");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: http://ghosertblog.github.io/ do you know how this blog works for hiddening the sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you out

Cheers !!

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xB5M2/)

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>    
    <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li> 
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<input type = "button" value="Try"/>
</div>
```

Comment: checked it is working.. Click on demo link it will navigate to jsfiddle.net

Comment: in the Demo, it is working,,, but add to my page, it doesn't, I found an example blog http://ghosertblog.github.io/